# Why am I getting a ConfigException 'Expected a comma separated list' error when creating a KafkaConsumer

Tags: groovy, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a `KafkaConsumer` with the following `Groovy` code:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.put('bootstrap.servers', "$SERVER_ADDRESS:$port")
props.put('key.deserializer', StringDeserializer.name,)
props.put('value.deserializer', StringDeserializer.name)
return new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props)
```

When I execute it, I am getting the following error:

> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value
>   localhost:9092 for configuration bootstrap.servers: Expected a comma
>   separated list.

My code essentially matches the example creation of a Consumer from [here](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

Why is my version not working?

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you using? In version 0.10 at least. The bootstrap.servers property is expecting a String array. you are only passing it as a single String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the props object is expecting its values to be of type Object, and not only of type String. Therefore, when `"$SERVER_ADDRESS:$port"` is added as a property, it isn't coerced into a String and is stored as a GStringImpl.

The type checking done before creating a KafkaConsumer knows how to handle a String property value but not a GStringImpl and throws an error.

Changing the line to this works:

```
props.put('bootstrap.servers', "$SERVER_ADDRESS:$port".toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 0.10.0 using the KafkaConsumer or KafkaProducer, it expects an array of Strings. You are passing a String.